# screen orientation on react native

Tags: react-native, orientation

I am trying to add the rotation functionality on react native using expo. Followed tutorials and searched on google and here but somehow none of them are working. The screen size is not getting detected when i rotate the simulator. Therefore it doesn't change from portrait to landscape or vice versa.
You can see the code below that i tried through following a working example but its not working when i apply it. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState("");
const window = useWindowDimensions();

 useEffect(() => {
  Dimensions.addEventListener("change", ({ window: { width, height } }) => {
   if (width < height) {
    // this is in portrait mode
    setOrientation("Portrait");
   } else {
    // this is in landscape mode
    setOrientation("Landscape");
   }
 });
}, []);

return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <Text style={{ color: "red", fontSize: 30, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
     {orientation}
   </Text>
  </View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  flex: 1,
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
 },
});
```

Comment: if you are using expo why don't you use that? https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/

Answer (score 1):

I have a very clean and efficient way to solve this

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/orientation-change)

Create a folder called `components` and inside that create a file called `Orientation.js`

Then inside `Orientation.js`

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const msp = (dim, limit) => {
  return dim.scale * dim.width >= limit || dim.scale * dim.height >= limit;
};

const isPortrait = () => {
  const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
  return dim.height >= dim.width;
};

const isLandscape = () => {
  const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
  return dim.width >= dim.height;
};

const isTablet = () => {
  const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
  return (
    (dim.scale < 2 && msp(dim, 1000)) || (dim.scale >= 2 && msp(dim, 1900))
  );
};

const isPhone = () => {
  return !isTablet();
};

export default {
  isPortrait,
  isLandscape,
  isTablet,
  isPhone,
};
```

Then set your `state` and `useEffect` like this

```
import Orientation from "./components/Orientation"

const [orientation, setOrientation] = useState(
    Orientation.isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    Dimensions.addEventListener('change', () => {
      setOrientation(Orientation.isPortrait() ? 'portrait' : 'landscape');
    });
  }, []);
```

This will work perfectly as you require

Results :

[image: Portrait Result]

[image: Landscape Result]

Comment: hey thank you for the answer it works but still there is one thing missing. the text does not rotate. it is just the text changes from portrait to landscape. what could be the reason for that?

Comment: i've added the results from my Device in the answer

Comment: thanks again but its very strange that the text is not rotating when i copy the exact code in the working example to my code. when i try the working example from the snack its perfectly working though.

Comment: Check your `state`, `useEffect`, `return statement` etc is it same or not...Also, I noticed `const window = useWindowDimensions();` in your code...You can remove that, its not doing anything

Comment: it didn't work. probably not the best practice but i added     transform: [{ rotate: "90deg" }],
and its working this way.